# hide nav based on scroll removing adding classes

Tags: javascript, css

I found a nav layout I would like to use but I seem to have run into 2 problems.

**problem #1** the transitions in the css do not seem to be transitioning smooth when scrolling up or down.

**problem #2** if the scroll position is not zero I do not want mainnav to shrink and i want the top nav to show or hide when i scroll up or down.. thats hard to word so what I am trying to accomplish exactly is the following

https://www.battlefield.com/games/battlefield-4/classes

now when you scroll down it hides the top nav but if you scroll just a little each way it will show or hide thats what I am trying to do.. but I dont want the 2nd nav to scale down unless the top is 0

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {

  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('.netnav').addClass('hide-nav');
    $('.netnav').removeClass('show-nav');
    $('.mainnav').addClass('scrolled');
   } 
   else {
    $('.netnav').addClass('show-nav');
    $('.netnav').removeClass('hide-nav');
    $('.mainnav').removeClass('scrolled');
   }
   
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.hwrap {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.netnav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

.netnav.show-nav {
  top: 0;
  transition-duration: .4s;
}

.netnav.hide-nav {
  transform: translate3d(0, -40px, 0);
  transition-duration: .4s;
}

.mainnav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 68px;
  z-index: 3;
  background: blue;
}

.mainnav {
  border-radius: 4px;
  left: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(15px);
  transition: transform .3s, width .3s;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
}

.mainnav.scrolled {
  top: 0;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 0;
  transform: translateY(0);
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform .3s, width .3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="hwrap">
  <div class="netnav">net nav</div>
  <div class="mainnav">main nav</div>
</header>

<div style="height: 100vh; display: block; background-color: gold">about</div>
<div style="height: 100vh; display: block; background-color: green">about</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/gos4hwp9/52/

### Explanation

1. Added `transition: all ease-in-out .4s` for smooth transitions of all properties
2. If `scrollTop > 0` added `margin: 0px` and `border-radius: 0px` to bottom (primary) nav, Else made `margin` and `border-radius` same as initial state
3. If `scrollDir == "down"` added `translateY(-50px)` to `header`, Else removed `translateY`
4. Moving the whole header will move both navs which is nice as compared to moving them individually

Comment: @Codi Welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've slightly changed your transitions and added transitions to the classes which you toggle.

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

.hwrap {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.netnav {
    position: fixed;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: .3s all;
}

.netnav.show-nav {
    top: 0;
    transition: .3s all;
}

.netnav.hide-nav {
    transform: translate3d(0, -40px, 0);
    transition: .3s all;
}

.mainnav {
    position: fixed;
    height: 68px;
    z-index: 3;
    background: blue;
}

.mainnav {
    border-radius: 4px;
    left: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 50px;
    position: relative;

    transform: translateY(15px);
    transition: .3s all;
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
}

.mainnav.scrolled {
    top: 0;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 0;
    transform: translateY(0);
    width: 100%;
    transition: .3s all;
}
```

Comment: that improved the transition but the animation still is not correct

Answer (score 0):

I followed the link you provided and edit the JavaScript and CSS.

Fixed the transitions in the CSS that does not seem smooth in transitioning when scrolling up or down using JavaScript.

You may visit this [pen](https://codepen.io/pen/) that I edited based on your snippet, and play around with it.

```js
        $(window).scroll(function(){

        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 15) {
           $('.netnav').addClass('hide-nav');
           $('.netnav').removeClass('show-nav');
           $('.mainnav').addClass('RemoveTop');
        }
        else {
           $('.netnav').addClass('show-nav');
           $('.netnav').removeClass('hide-nav');
           $('.mainnav').removeClass('RemoveTop');
           $('.mainnav').removeClass('scrolled');  
        }
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
           $('.mainnav').addClass('scrolled');
        }
        else {
           $('.netnav').removeClass('scrolled'); 
        }
    });
```

```css
        body {
        margin: 0px;
    }


    .hwrap{
      display:block;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
    }


    .netnav{  
      position: fixed;
      height: 40px;
      width: 100%; 
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: blue;
      transition: all .3s;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .netnav.show-nav { 
      top: 0;
      transition-duration: .4s;
    }

    .netnav.hide-nav {
      transform: translate3d(0,-40px,0);
      transition-duration: .4s;
    }

    .mainnav{
      position: fixed;
      height: 68px; 
      z-index: 3;
      background: blue;
    }

    .mainnav {
        border-radius: 4px;
        left: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        top: 50px;
        position: relative;
        transform: translateY(15px);
        transition: all .3s,width .3s;
        width: calc(100% - 60px);
    }

    .mainnav.RemoveTop {
      top: 0px;
    }


    .mainnav.scrolled { 
      height: 60px;
      border-radius: 0;
      transform: translateY(0);
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <header class="hwrap">
 <div class="netnav">net nav</div>
 <div class="mainnav">main nav</div>
 </header>
 
 <div style="height: 100vh; display: block; background-color: gold">about</div>
 <div style="height: 100vh; display: block; background-color: green">about</div>
```

Comment: @v-soriano is there a way to add the scroll when not a 0px like it is on the site?

Comment: I've finally come up with what you are trying to accomplish.  @Codi You can add this to your code via [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/) demo code. If you want the detailed analysis, you can visit this [site](http://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/) for reference. Hope it can resolve now your problem.

Comment: @V Soriano I seen that jfiddle the above you showed works for one part but not the other.